# Special character are contained in password and it breaks the URL

Tags: perl, curl, url-encoding

I run a curl request within my perl script and if password or user name contains any special character(&) it break the url. Please let me know how can i solve this.

```
 my $json="curl --user $userName:$password http://git.sample.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/TEAMS/repos/ ";

my $decodedJson = decode_json($json);
```

Comment: use a perl module like `WWW::Curl` instead of a cmdline call

Comment: i am looking for a native way

Comment: The native way in Perl would be not to use curl, but to use LWP::UserAgent instead.

Comment: The `curl` command line program is not native to Perl and, for that matter, many systems do not have `curl` installed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i implemented @simbabque way using `WP::UserAgent`.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $req = new HTTP::Request(GET => 'http://git.sample.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/TEAMS/repos/');
  $req->authorization_basic($userName,$password);
  my $response = $ua->request($req);

  #handle error
  unless ($response->is_success) {
        die $response->status_line;
  }
  my $content = $response->decoded_content();
  if (utf8::is_utf8($content)) {
      binmode STDOUT,':utf8';
  } else {
      binmode STDOUT,':raw';
  }
 my $json=$content;

 my $decodedJson = decode_json($json);
```